# Silex linking to an inapp wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, routes, twig, silex

Hi all i have  silex application but i want the app to redirect to /blog of the site which directs me to the wordpress blog of the site but it keeps giving me 404 page.. i configured the app route to return a custom page of error 404 
here is my code

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';



$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());

$app->error(function (\Exception $e,$code) use ($app){
    switch($code){

        case 404:
        return  $app['twig']->render('404.php.twig');
        break;

        default:

        return $app['twig']->render('index.php.twig');
    }





});
$app->get('/blog', function() use ($app) {
    return $app->redirect('/blog');
});

$app->get('/', function() use ($app){
    return $app['twig']->render('index.php.twig');
});

$app->get('/ContactUs', function() use ($app){
    return $app['twig']->render('contactus.php.twig');
});
$app->get('/Solutions', function() use ($app){
    return $app['twig']->render('solutions.php.twig');
});
$app->get('/OurProducts', function() use ($app){
    return $app['twig']->render('ourproducts.php.twig');
});
$app->run();
?>
```

Comment: you might want to do this with Apache as a rewrite rule

Comment: hello oliverBs.. plz ow do i do dat?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708